# How do we show a matrix is similar?

Tags: linear-algebra

My idea is that we should find the eigenvalues first from our matrix (lets call it $A$)

and then build a matrix $P$ using the eigenvectors from $A$

Then we calculate $P^{-1}AP$ for the similar matrix?

Does this sound right?

Comment: What is the meaning of asserting that a matrix $A$ is similar? Similar to what?

Comment: Finding a matrix similar to A

Comment: Take $A$ itself.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: You want to find a matrix similar to $A$. Since $A=\operatorname{Id}^{-1}A\operatorname{Id}$, $A$ itself will work.

Comment: I guess you may have omitted an essential part of your problem. Your problem may have been: "show a matrix is similar *to a diagonal matrix*". The word *diagonal* is the key here. The problem simply doesn't make sense without it. And yes, finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors is a way to go.

Comment: gotcha 
my bad about that

Comment: Start with the definition of similarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditions for similarity of two matrices $A$ and $B$:

a. $B=X^{-1}AX$ for some invertible matrix $X$. (sufficient and necessary)

b. $A$ and $B$ are matrices of the same linear transformation under different bases. (sufficient and necessary)

c. $\lambda E-A$ is equivalent to $\lambda E-B$ where $E$ is the identity matrix. (sufficient and necessary)

d. $A$ and $B$ have the same determinant divisors at all levels. (sufficient and necessary)

e. $A$ and $B$ have the same invariant divisors. (sufficient and necessary)

f. $A$ and $B$ have the same elementary divisors. (sufficient and necessary)

g. $A$ and $B$ have the same characteristic polynomials. (necessary and insufficient)

h. $A$ and $B$ have the same determinants. (necessary and insufficient)

i. $A$ and $B$ have the same minimum polynomials. (necessary and insufficient)

Comment: Hope the above conditions can help you find a matrix similar to $A$.